# React js update object value in an array with n number of input data useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm creating a todolist with react js, the website allow me to add multiple task in a single instance, which mean that i can add any number of input field and fill it with data and save it. My method is to use a pre-defined json object, whenever i add an input field, useEffect will handle it by pushing the pre-defined json object into an array and useState will set the newly array.
This my code for adding a input field or a child:

```
//hook for the input field/children count
   const [taskCount , setTaskCount] = useState(1);

//hook for all the input data, the initial data is an empty array
//whenever the taskCount increases, it will set a new array
const [test , setTest] = useState([]);

 //pre-defined json object schema
 const schema = 
   {   
       id : 0,
       choice : '',
       questName : '',
       location : '',
       time : '',
       linkedQuestB : '',
       linkedQuestA : '',
       status : [
                    {id : 'not_started' , label : 'not_started' , checked : false},
                    {id : 'in_progress' , label : 'in_progress' , checked : false},
                    {id : 'done' , label : 'done' , checked : false},
                ],

   }
//function onClick for adding input
//whenever a new input is created
//temp id is increment for input value onChange
  function addField () 
   {
       let initilaTest = test ;
       const temp = {...schema};
       temp.id = taskCount;
       initilaTest.push(temp);
       setTest(initilaTest);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        addField();
        console.log(test)
    } , [taskCount])

const someExampleFunction () 
{
return (
                    <img 
                        src = {plus}
                        alt = {'exist non'}
                        onClick = {()=> setTaskCount(taskCount+ 1)}
                    />
             <exampleFunctionforInput > 
                {[...Array(taskCount)].map((value , index)=>{ return (<TodoFieldSet  id ={index} 
                 key = {index}
                update = {updateval} />)})}
            </exampleFunctionforInput >)}
```

So to change the value in each respective input, i use onChange method. The method for handling the onChange method is as follow, whenever the input value change, onChange will fire the update function, which takes the index as param id and a param of event.target to change the respective input value with looping the key of the object and matching the e.target.id and finally change the state of `test`. It does worked, but obviously whenever the number of input field increases, typing in the input field get slower, because there is a ton of object in the array to loop through and find respective data. So is there a better ways of doin it.
Code for input field components :

```
 const inputProps = 
    [   
        {id : 'questName' , name : 'Quest Name',type :'text' , },

        {id : 'time' , name : 'Time',type :'text' ,},

        {id : 'linkedQuestB' , name : 'Linked Quest Before',type : 'text',},

        {id : 'linkedQuestA' , name : 'Linked Quest After',type : 'text',},

        {id : 'location' , name : 'location',type : 'text',},
    ]
//handling the onChange
   const updateval = (index , target  ) => 
    {
        let temp = [...test];
        for(let key in temp[index])
        {
            if(key === target.id )
            {
                temp[index][key] = target.value;
            }
        }
        setTest(temp);
        
        
    }
function exampleFunctionforInput ({id , update})
{
return (
{inputProps && inputProps.map((value , index)=> 
            {   
               return (  
               <TodoInWrapper  key = {index} id = {value.name + id}>
                    <label htmlFor = {value.id}>{value.name}</label>
                    <input 
                        id = {value.id} 
                        type = {value.type}
                        onChange = {e => update(id , e.target)}
                        />
                </TodoInWrapper>)
            })};)
}
```

Don't mind the all the React Components tag, they are styled components.

Comment: This may be a better question for [https://codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), but please review [their help section](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) first to see what kind of questions you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

You're **looping** through all elements to find the element then you update it, if you want to avoid that, you can use a key-value map, where that will enhance performance from O(n) to O(1)

Other possible optimisations could be done, which I believe will make difference:

1. Eliminate mutations
2. Making functions pure (they have side effects)
3. Name of components should start with Capital letter in React
4. To pass more predictable keys to `TodoInWrapper`
5. Use useCallback for functions within the Component

*I couldn't give example code because the provided code is hard to be used as a reference*